# libGDX How to match user click to object position?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to develop my own game by following kilobolt.com tutorial and altering it to what I'm trying to create, but found myself in a pickle...

A bit of a background:
In the Zombie Bird tutorial, inside the Bird object there is an onClick() method that being called inside the touchDown() method of a different class that implement InputProcessor. When the game run and the user tap the screen, the bird react by going up a bit.

What I want to know:
I try to create something a bit more detailed, that require the user to tap the exact position of the bird on the screen while it moves, and every time the bird being tapped, it calls for an Animation.

I tried a few codes that I found in Google and modified them when they did not work, but the game just crashed.

Being new to game developing I ask of you to please bare with my incompetence.

Comment: Please post some code showing the issue that occured when you tested it for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create two Circle objects from libGDX's Circle class. One circle would follow the bird on the screen, while the other one is positioned based on where the user touches the screen. The if statement would look like:

```
if(user.getCircle().intersects(bird.getCircle()) && screen.isTouched())
    animation();
```

Not very complicated, probably not even the best way to implement, but it's something.

Comment: Thanks, looks simple enough. But won't I need OrthographicCamera variable? In most of the examples I found there was a need for one...

Comment: Can you post one of the examples you're talking about? I'm not sure why you'd need an OrthographicCamera variable, but then again, I haven't used libGDX in months.

Comment: Unfortunately I've deleted the examples I used, but here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645422/how-to-match-user-click-and-the-sprite-object-position-in-libgdx-framework you can find a code example I tried to alter. Give me your opinion about it, and if you won't find the need to change the code example you gave me, I'll mark your answer with V, and hope that it will work when it will be time to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use math to convert screen co-ordinates to cam co-ordinates:

```
//Example:
float ScreenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); 
float ScreenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
// on a 1080p screen this would return ScreenWidth = 1080, ScreenHeight = 1920; 
//now you get the screen co-ordinates and convert them to cam co-ordinates:
float x1 = Gdx.input.getX();
float y1 = Gdx.input.getY();
float x1cam = (x1/ScreenWidth)*CamWidth
float y1cam = (y1/ScreenHeight)*CamHeight

// now you can use the if statement
if(sprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(x1cam, y1cam)) {
    //Go whatever you want to do with the bird/ sprite 
    // for more accuracy I would recommend drawing a shape that matches your sprite like a circle and check if the input co-ordinates are withing the circle.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My code should work if the height and width specified in cam.setToOrtho(bool, height, width) are the same as the phone's height and width. If they aren't equal, then you'll get the same problem as in that thread. If you do have different heights and widths, then you'll just have to use the cam.unproject(vec3) to get the correct x and y coords for the user.getCircle(). So, your setCircle() method would look something like

```
public void setCircle(Vector3 touchPos)
{
    cam.unproject(touchPos);
    this.circle.set(touchPos.x, touchPos.y, touchPos.z);
}
```

Again, that code only applies if your phone's height and width differ from the orthographic camera's height and width.